# How to set up exit link?

Tags: html, dns

how to set up outgoing link when click another link. 
domain A to domain B but domain A is still conserved in the front.

example visit rojadirecta

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark as your question was very unclear.

I'm guessing that you want to open a link in a new window/tab?

```
<a href="your-link.com" target="_blank">Your link</a>
```

This tells the browser that you want to open the link in a new window whilst leaving the current page as is.